# GPS Coordinates to POI

Tags: reverse-geocoding, point-of-interest

I need to convert a pair of (latitude, longitude) coordinates to a POI if available. I am able to reverse-geocode the coordinates to an address. After that is there a way to map the address to a POI or anything else ?

Could someone point me to free API if available ?

Comment: What kind of point of interest? Do you already have a database?

Comment: Looking for things like restaurants, fast food, recreation centers etc. I am using the tiger and osm data sets for reverse geocoding.

Comment: Probably just look up the interesting attributes in your OSM set then.